# Error CS0103 FastReport.net

Tags: c#, dataset, fastreport

i am C#.net Windows Form developer . 
i am using FastReport.net . but have some error .

this is my code :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("MyCnnStr");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from test";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dap.Fill(ds, "ds");
report1.RegisterData(ds.Tables[0],"ds");
report1.GetDataSource("ds").Enabled = true;
report1.Load("Untitled.frx");
report1.Show();
```

but my error :

[image]

what is my wrong ?

Comment: Where you defined these `name`, `tel` and `fax`?

Comment: i solved this problem . thanks alote

Comment: @MiladCoder please can you share how have you managed to solve this?

Comment: i have the same problem could you say how you solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If name, tel and fax is names of tables, then you can try to write following:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("MyCnnStr");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from test";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dap.Fill(ds, "ds");
report1.RegisterData(ds.Tables[0],"ds");
report1.GetDataSource("ds").Enabled = true;
report1.GetDataSource("name").Enabled = true; // add this part
report1.GetDataSource("tel").Enabled = true;  //
report1.GetDataSource("fax").Enabled = true;  //
report1.Load("Untitled.frx");
report1.Show();
```

Also you can try delete connections in Designer mode.

Answer (score 0):

`CS0103` may appear if you casually print symbol from other keyboard layout.

For example: `E` (English), `Е` (Russian), `Ε` (Greek).